# is there a Objective-c method that can put NSString into stdout.

Tags: stdout, nslog

NSLog puts something into stderr,
is there a Objective-c method that can put NSString into stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helpful?

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-print-nsstring-to-stdout.html